# Problem with AppWindow.Title and Unicode from a Maui application

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am trying to set the Window title of a Maui application to be a value containing Unicode (say Japanese) characters.  The Japanese characters (and other unicode characters) appear as '?'

I set the title as follows

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
  Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
  window.Title = "Hello こんにちは World Test";
  return window;
}
```

In a minimal Maui application ... this has the expected result.

In my much more complex application (with a bit of Windows specific behavior and API calls), the Japanese appears as ????.

My guess is that I am messing up the low-level window somehow.

What might cause this problem ?

---

Upon more investigation ... it seems that somehow the presence of a a lifecycle event causes the problem.  I have a

```
 builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
                {
                events.AddWindows(win => win
                        .OnWindowCreated((window) => {
```

When I remove the event, the problem goes away.  The event implementation itself was just an empty code block.

I cannot replicate this in a 'minimal' application

Comment: if you have a simple repro case I'd file a bug on the MAUI github

Answer (score 0):

I found that the behavior is correct if I set the title this way

```
IWindow iWindow = Application.Windows[0];
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window xxx = iWindow as Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window;
xxx.Title = "hello there こんにちは ";
```

If it is set like this

```
IWindow iWindow = Application.Windows[0];
MauiWinUIWindow www = iWindow.Handler.PlatformView as MauiWinUIWindow;
xxx.Title = "hello there こんにちは ";
```

Either no title is visible or the unicode is as ??? depending on if         ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar is set.